# R ggplot geom_bar create different output

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I want to create a bar chart for my data set (df) and I'm using this script:

```
p1<-ggplot(df,aes(x=variable,y=log10(value),fill=Subject))
p1+ geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "dodge")
```

It crates this plot:
[image: Output]

The total of 'İşçi Hakları 021D' is 56,173 and the total of 
 'İşçi Hakları 111D' is 32,760. So how does 111D create a longer bar than 021D?

[!! To get data frame for this plot please click here !!](https://bulut.omu.edu.tr/index.php/s/Xy1fZuLXjgXs6LU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `ggplot` is not grouping in the way you'd expect- it might be easiest to manually summarize your data so that you know exactly what you're plotting:

```
manual_summary <- df %>% 
  group_by(Subject, variable) %>%
  summarize(logeach = log10(sum(value)))

ggplot(manual_summary, aes(x = variable, y = logeach, fill = Subject)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Lucke C .If you can able to tell me what is the problem in ggplot?

Comment: @eabanoz I'm afraid I'm not sure exactly, but my guess is that ggplot was returning the y value grouped only by your "Selection" rather than your variable.